# GridView paging in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging, custompaging

I am using `PageIndexChanging` event for handling GridView paging in C#. But don't know how can to use PageSize/PageNumber/PageCount there. In other word my code is forced to return all data always. Note following code:

```
protected void grdList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        grdList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdList.DataSource = MyGetData();
        grdList.DataBind();
}
```

Now how can I use real paging in this code?

Notice that `MyGetData` has an overload that get `PageIndex` and `PageSize` too.

**UPDATE**

I have set `PageSize` and enabled `AllowPaging` too. I know if I use declarative data binding I should supply GridView with count of all data. Question is how can can use count in this method.

**UPDATE 2**
It seems that such a thing I need is not possible, refer to [Problem with Efficient Gridview paging without datasource control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518968/problem-with-efficient-gridview-paging-without-datasource-control)

Comment: Do you mean you are unsure how to limit the data your MyGetData() method returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient paging in GridView needs count of data, otherwise GridView loads all data in each page. As there is no way to tell GridView what is the count of data when not using DataSource controls, it's impossible to have efficient paging in GridView without having DataSource control. For more info go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518968/problem-with-efficient-gridview-paging-without-datasource-control) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [PageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx) in the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `PageSize="10"`

see in this link: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1249-Grid-View-Paging-Sorting.aspx

Comment: he can set PageSize to any value - it doesnt have to be 10 - infact a control can be made to set the pagesize dynamically if necessary

Comment: sample code in your given link loads all data whenever you navigate across pages in pager. A real paging mechanism loads only data related to a single page. A real paging has a very high positive impact on application performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyGetData` method already accepts pageindex and pagesize, then all you'd need is:

```
protected void grdList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdList.DataSource = MyGetData(e.NewPageIndex, grdList.PageSize);
    grdList.DataBind();
}
```

but this seems a bit too simplistic so I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: I used this way. This works good. But pager does not work. Because GridView does not know what is the count of data.