# Overriding gridview class asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

asp.net noob here. I'm trying to override/extend Gridview for paging as specified in this topic:
[Problem with Efficient Gridview paging without datasource control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518968/problem-with-efficient-gridview-paging-without-datasource-control)

code-behind:

```
namespace MyCode
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    ....
    }
}
namespace cly.Web.CustomControls
    {
         public class clyGridView : GridView
         {
          ...code
         }
    }
```

How would I declare this new gridview in my .aspx file? I have tried using the class as

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyCode._Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="cly.Web.CustomControls" %>    
...
<asp:clyGridView ID="MyResults" runat="server"> </asp:clyGridView>
```

but that doesn't work and I get this error

```
The type or namespace name 'clyGridView' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a tag prefix for your custom control.

Add

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="cly" namespace="cly.Web.CustomControls" %>
```

to your page and use the tag prefix with your custom control

```
<cly:clyGridView ID="MyResults" runat="server"> </cly:clyGridView>
```

Comment: I get the error: The name 'MyResults' does not exist in the current context. My codebehind isn't seeing the new clyGridView for some reason

Comment: `Results` doesn't occur in your sample code so this is an unrelated new problem. To be quite honest I don't think it's a good idea to create custom controls just after starting in ASP.NET. In 90% of all cases people try to invent functionality that is already there.

Comment: Check your **Default.aspx.designer.cs** - it must contain `protected global::cly.Web.CustomControls.clyGridView MyResults;`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to make the paging efficient, you should only create a custom datasource.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16988/Creating-a-custom-DataSourceControl-with-full-desi) that teaches you how to do it.

Creating a custom girdview is not needed.

If you implement the datasource properly, gridview will bind to it perfectly and you will get the efficient paging you desire.